# Cannot build tests with Gradle (decard-gradle)

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I created gradle with from [deckrd-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) project. The problem is that when I run test (in Android Studio) I get this error: `No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.getBootClasspath() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

My gradle file:

```
(removed it because here wa everything OK)
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {

        // given
        Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity_.class).create().get();

        // when

        // then
        assertThat(activity).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In file build.gradle (but not for module - for all project) I had 0.9.+ version of gradle.

After changing to 0.10.+ everything starts